# VB.NET UserControl

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I am trying to create a UserControl in VB.net, under VS2010. I have the code for the UserControl and I would like to add it to a form. My problem is that, according to every book and forum I have seen, after I build the UserControl, it should show up in the Toolbox. It doesn't. I even downloaded code from a book, the code executes perfectly, but their TrafficLight control doesn't go in the Toolbox (even though the book says it should - and that the only way to set its properties and to add it to the form is through the Control properties). I have tried to add the control to the form manually, by declaring it

```
Dim myObj As New SomeClass.SomeControl
```

and in the Designer.vb, identical with the buttons on the form:

```
Friend WithEvents myObj As SomeClass.SomeControl
```

With both, I get an error saying

```
'myObj' is already declared as 'Friend WithEvents myObj As SomeControl' in this class.
```

And either way, I get an error when I try to look at the design:

```
Could not find type 'SomeClass.SomeControl'. Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced. If this type is part of your development project, make sure the project has been successfully built using settings for your current platform or AnyCPU.
```

The control by itself builds and shows up in design view (not in the Toolbox though, even though it `Imports System.ComponentModel` and `Inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl` and... what else ? I tried to build it in a separate project, to see if I creating a separate dll will make a difference, though I really want it in the same project. 
Please help ! (BTW I have reinstalled VS2010 and it did no good)
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking on the toolbox and selecting 'Choose Items'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in Tools / Options / Windows Forms Designer and set "AutoToolboxPopulate" to True (but note that this can take a noticeable amount of time if you haver many (i.e. dozens) of user controls.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me a lot in troubleshooting. Any idea why a control would show up in x86 but not in x64 ?

Comment: No - never heard of that oddity before!